# Posting single line question and answer as visitor/spammer without proper signing/authentication

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

Why does the visitors to the TeX.SX (may be prospective TeX.SX user) have option to post Q & A as Guest and without proper signing/authentication before posting.

For example (Visitor to TeX.SX sees like this (screenshots attached)):

1. Possibility to **Post a new question as Guest** with Question boxes wide open before registration/login. (Screenshot below)

   **Implications**: I see lot of answers with one line, "saying thanks", "Use this template", "it works for me too" etc...  Are we attracting new users at cost of  spammers and casual  people because of which it creates more work load on current Users(commentators/editors) and many hard working people who maintain the clean site.

   [image]
2. Should we have **Improve the Question** option open to unregistered users/visitors? I know it will be peer-reviewed but why to take up double work?

   **Improve the Question** by Visitor (Screenshot below)

   [image]
3. Should we have **Improve the Answer** option open to unregistered users/visitors?

   **Improve the Answer** by Visitor (Screenshot below)

   [image]

Finally, Should we open too much as to allow anyone to touch the Q&A text? Why not give access to only `Registered users` see "Improve" and "edit" features.

Comment: when an anonymous user edits a post, this edit has to be reviewed by the community, they can't just edit directly like 2k+ users. But the number of good edits from anonymous users is very low in my experience, I'd examine the suggested edits in detail before deciding to remove that feature. And the low barrier to entry is intentional, it is only disabled on the largest sites like Stack Overflow (you have to register there to ask a question, but you can still post answers anonymously).